# Receiving dynamic object in PageMethod from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic, pagemethods

I created a `new object()` in Javascript, put some values into it and passed it to a `PageMethod`...

```
var filters = new object();

filters.Name = $("#tbxName").val();
filters.Age = parseInt($("#tbxAge").val());

PageMethods.getPeople(filters, getPeopleCallback);
```

... which, in it's signature, receives an `dynamic` argument.

```
[WebMethod]
public static object getPeople(dynamic filters)
{
    ...
```

The whole code compiles and run with no problems, except for the server side PageMethod, which understands the `dynamic` parameter as a `Dictionary`.

When I debug the code to see the definition of the `filters` object, it shows me the following type: `filters = {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>}`

So, the only way deal with it is using it as a `Dictionary`...

```
var name = filters["Name"];
var age = filters["Age"] as int?;
```

.. But my intention was to use it as a Dynamic object

```
var name = filters.Name;
var age = filters.Age;
```

I know that this is not a big deal at all, and there is absolutely no problem for me to access it as a Dictionary (and I also know I can make a `DynamicObject` "Proxy" to access the Dictionary like a dynamic object).

I just want to understand this. So:

1. Why the PageMethod understands it as a Dictionary?
2. Is there a way to make this work as a Dynamic object (except for the "Proxy" approach)?

I was hoping that this could work because I usually define those `Filter` Classes on Server Side and create it in Javascript following the same structure, and the PageMethod understands it and convert it correctly when I define that Type as a argument (eg: `getPeople(Filters filters)`). So, I was wondering if it could do that also with dynamic objects (saving me time and unnecessary classes).

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: I would be surprised if `PageMethod` understands `dynamic`. `PageMethod` is the legacy ASMX-style web service, which has been in "legacy" state since before `dynamic` existed. Also, in general, it's a bad idea to pass platform-specific data to web services, and `dynamic` is specific to .NET.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Be surprised then. ASMX and page methods work fine with `dynamic` typed return values. More importantly, WCF/DCJS doesn't handle `dynamic` input parameters any better than ASMX/JSS does, which makes the old ASMX vs. WCF debate a moot point to bring up anyway.

Comment: @DaveWard: what about in this case, where `dynamic` is used as an input parameter? Also, in the case of a return value, what does a `dynamic` return look like to a SOAP client? Or were  you referring only to REST? Also, can you say what you mean by "works fine"? I said "understands".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'm not sure what it does for SOAP. I only use ASMX for its ScriptService "mode". If you return a `dynamic` object through ASMX as JSON, it serializes as key/value pairs, basically just like a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: @DaveWard: `Dictionary<string,object>` seems to be what the OP is complaining about...

Comment: @JohnSaunders: `Dictionary<string, object>` is the correct serialization (JSS' at least; DCJS makes ugly JSON out of Dictionaries). It's just an annoying *de*serialization, which is what he's running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason that the page method treats that as a Dictionary is because of how JavaScriptSerializer works internally. Since all JSON objects can be represented as a `Dictionary<string, object>`, JSS' first pass is to convert the JSON string into a Dictionary (if no custom converters for the target type are registered) and you end up with that Dictionary as the end result of the conversion for dynamics.
2. Not easily.

You could experiment with writing your own JavaScriptConverter for `dynamic`. This is an example of something in the same ballpark that I wrote a while back: https://gist.github.com/6cfcdfdf2a117fa5e81b

Mine's customizing the serialization behavior instead of deserialization, but you can implement your own code in the Deserialize method to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'll also check your link and do some experiments... ;)